# Apache Superset error in the encoding in the docker-based Version

Tags: utf-8, mysql-connector, apache-superset

I want to connect superset with a mysql database, which contains a table with some greek letters (utf8).

When I install superset [from scratch](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch) it works fine, displaying the greek letters correctly.

When I install I choose the [docker installation](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose), it displays ??? where the greek letters are. Notice that in the docker version, I install the the drivers with `echo "mysqlclient" >> ./docker/requirements-local.txt`, as it is recommended in the [documentation](https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/dockeradddrivers).

The connection string I use in both cases is `mysql://<UserName>:<DBPassword>@<Database Host>/<Database Name>`

Any idea why this problem with the encoding, **only** in the docker-based version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding problem is solved using `mysql-connector-python` drivers, instead of the default `mysqlclient`!

---

- Append `mysql-connector-python` to `./docker/requirements-local.txt`
- from superset, connect to `mysql` with this driver, using the following `sqlalchemy` uri `mysql+mysqlconnector://<user>:<password>@<host>[:<port>]/<dbname>`